# Что за ошибка при запуске openvpn?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openvpn

Вот такая проблема возникла, не знаю, как решить:

> Mon Jan 28 06:55:20 2019 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 22 2017
>   Mon Jan 28 06:55:20 2019 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
>   Mon Jan 28 06:55:20 2019 Control Channel Authentication: using 'ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
>   Mon Jan 28 06:55:20 2019 ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such file or directory (errno=2)

Comment: Нет файла `Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such file or directory`

Comment: И как с этим быть?

Comment: Ну можно проверить права, наличие этого файла по требуемому пути, запустить с `sudo`. Создать этот файл.

Comment: Только что проверил: total 0
crw------- 1 root root 10, 200 Jan 29 04:58 tun

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir /dev/net
mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200
```

Проверка на модуль tun

```
lsmod | grep tun
```

Если его нет, попробовать его загрузить с помощью команды

```
modprobe tun
```